# Have superuser account using passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

How can i create a superuser authentication with passport js and express here is what my looks like

```
const jwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('./config');


module.exports = function(passport){
  let ops = {}
  ops.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
  ops.secretOrKey = config.secret
  passport.use(new jwtStrategy(ops, (jwt_payload,done)=>{
    console.log(jwt_payload);
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id,(err,user)=>{
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return done(null,false)
      }
      if (user) {
        return done(null,user)
      }else {
        return done(null,false)
      }
    })
  }))
}
```

But when i can authenticate the user has access to all routes i want to have another auth where users will have access to a particular route `superuser` or`admin`

Comment: you need to store somewhere the `role` of the user and run checks against the role , there are many modules on npm search for passportjs roles

Comment: Cab you recommend one please

Comment: https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl/blob/master/Readme.md , https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-roles and many others